# Gremlin get all incoming and outgoing vertex, including their edges and directions

Tags: java, graph, neo4j, titan, gremlin

I spent a week at Gremlin shell trying to compose one query to
get all incoming and outgoing vertexes, including their edges and directions. All i tried everything.

```
g.V("name","testname").bothE.as('both').select().back('both').bothV.as('bothV').select(){it.map()}
```

output i need is (just example structure ):

[v{'name':"testname"}]___[ine{edge_name:"nameofincomingedge"}]____[v{name:'nameofconnectedvertex']

[v{'name':"testname"}]___[oute{edge_name:"nameofoutgoingedge"}]____[v{name:'nameofconnectedvertex']

So i just whant to get 1) all Vertices with exact name , edge of each this vertex (including type inE or outE), and connected Vertex. And ideally after that i want to get their map() so i'l get complete object properties. i dont care about the output style, i just need all of information present, so i can manipulate with it after. I need this to train my Gremlin, but Neo4j examples are welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There's a variety of ways to approach this.  Here's a few ideas that will hopefully inspire you to an answer:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerGraphFactory.createTinkerGraph()                                                                                                        
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> g.V('name','marko').transform{[v:it,inE:it.inE().as('e').outV().as('v').select().toList(),outE:it.outE().as('e').inV().as('v').select().toList()]}
==>{v=v[1], inE=[], outE=[[e:e[9][1-created->3], v:v[3]], [e:e[7][1-knows->2], v:v[2]], [e:e[8][1-knows->4], v:v[4]]]}
```

The `transform` converts the incoming vertex to a `Map` and does internal traversal over in/out edges.  You could also use `path` as follows to get a similar output:

```
gremlin> g.V('name','marko').transform{[v:it,inE:it.inE().outV().path().toList().toList(),outE:it.outE().inV().path().toList()]}       
==>{v=v[1], inE=[], outE=[[v[1], e[9][1-created->3], v[3]], [v[1], e[7][1-knows->2], v[2]], [v[1], e[8][1-knows->4], v[4]]]}
```

I provided these answers using TinkerPop 2.x as that looked like what you were using as judged from the syntax.  TinkerPop 3.x is now available and if you are just getting started, you should take a look at the latest that has to offer:

http://tinkerpop.incubator.apache.org/

Under 3.0 syntax you might do something like this:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('name','marko').as('a').bothE().bothV().where(neq('a')).path()
==>[v[1], e[9][1-created->3], v[3]]
==>[v[1], e[7][1-knows->2], v[2]]
==>[v[1], e[8][1-knows->4], v[4]]
```

I know that you wanted to know what the direction of the edge in the output but that's easy enough to detect on analysis of the path.

UPDATE: Here's the above query written with Daniel's suggestion of `otherV` usage:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('name','marko').bothE().otherV().path()
==>[v[1], e[9][1-created->3], v[3]]
==>[v[1], e[7][1-knows->2], v[2]]
==>[v[1], e[8][1-knows->4], v[4]]
```

To see the data from this you can use `by()` to pick apart each `Path` object - The extension to the above query applies `valueMap` to each piece of each `Path`:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('name','marko').bothE().otherV().path().by(__.valueMap(true)) 
==>[{label=person, name=[marko], id=1, age=[29]}, {label=created, weight=0.4, id=9}, {label=software, name=[lop], id=3, lang=[java]}]
==>[{label=person, name=[marko], id=1, age=[29]}, {label=knows, weight=0.5, id=7}, {label=person, name=[vadas], id=2, age=[27]}]
==>[{label=person, name=[marko], id=1, age=[29]}, {label=knows, weight=1.0, id=8}, {label=person, name=[josh], id=4, age=[32]}]
```

Comment: Very Thank you Stephen! I will try this at home, and if it helps, I'l give you bounty. Also I'm interested if you think that Titan and gremlin is a good choice to build large date social network, based on this technologies. Have a nice day!

Comment: Note that `.as('a').bothE().bothV().where(neq('a'))` can be rewritten as `.bothE().otherV()`.

Comment: dah - forgot `otherV`

Comment: Thank you Steven for your answer! I tested this and it seems like this is what i need, but i still cannot get .map() (I mean full object representation) of each resulted element. Opening bounty for you anyway.

Comment: getting the data as a `Map` is just a transformation of each `Path` object returned.  see my updated answer for TP3.  In TP2, you would have to use `transform` i guess.