# Gremlin 3 - get all incoming and outgoing vertices, including their edges and directions and including vertices without edges

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, graph-databases, gremlin, tinkerpop3

I'm trying to compose one query to get all incoming and outgoing vertices, including their edges and directions, which would however return those vertices without edges as well.

I was able to work around the problem for now by forcing everything to have at least one edge, but it's something I'd like to avoid.

Maybe worth noting that I use the Graph API of Azure CosmosDB: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/gremlin-support

This is the query I'm using to return all vertices with their edges and related vertices:

```
g.V().hasLabel('User').as('User').bothE().as('Edge').otherV().as('RelatedObject').path()
```

I got this from: [Gremlin get all incoming and outgoing vertex, including their edges and directions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33676566/gremlin-get-all-incoming-and-outgoing-vertex-including-their-edges-and-directio)

This query produces the result which I am able to easily parse in a C# application later, however this query doesn't return vertices which don't have edges.

Any ideas?

*EDIT*

The closest I've got is this:

```
g.V().hasLabel("User").as("User").map(bothE().otherV().fold()).as("RelatedObjects").select("User", "RelatedObjects")
```

However this approach doesn't display edges between `User` and `RelatedObjects`. I also need edges to be able to map these related objects to parent object properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can drop all the step labels and use of side-effects - just use `project()`:

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('person').
......1>   project('user','edges','relatedVertices').
......2>     by().
......3>     by(bothE().fold()).
......4>     by(both().fold())
==>[user:v[1],edges:[e[9][1-created->3],e[7][1-knows->2],e[8][1-knows->4]],relatedVertices:[v[3],v[2],v[4]]]
==>[user:v[2],edges:[e[7][1-knows->2]],relatedVertices:[v[1]]]
==>[user:v[4],edges:[e[10][4-created->5],e[11][4-created->3],e[8][1-knows->4]],relatedVertices:[v[5],v[3],v[1]]]
==>[user:v[6],edges:[e[12][6-created->3]],relatedVertices:[v[3]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

g.V().hasLabel("User").as("User").bothE().as(“edges”).map(select(“edges”).inV().fold()).as("RelatedObjects").select("User", "RelatedObjects",”edges”)

Comment: Interesting approach, however it only shows one edge from each user. I tried to add `.fold()` step after `.bothE()` step but that caused an exception in Microsoft.Azure.Graphs library.

Comment: Actually it works (it just displays one `User` for each edge it has but it's good enough)!

Comment: Sorry, it actually still ignores vertices which have no edges... I tried this one: `.as('User').bothE().as('Edge').map(select('Edge').otherV()).as('RelatedVertex').select('Vertex', 'Edge', 'RelatedVertex')`. Must be too tired.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have you graph to test with but this general pattern should work for you I think.

```
g.withSideEffect('x', [] as Set).                        
     V().hasLabel("user").store('x').                                    
     bothE().store('x').                                  
     otherV().store('x').                                 
     cap('x')
```

Edited to not use Set

```
g.withSideEffect('x', []).                        
     V().has('code',"AUS").store('x').                                    
     bothE().store('x').                                  
     otherV().store('x').                                 
     cap('x').unfold().dedup().fold()
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with Microsoft.Azure.Graphs: Gremlin Query Compilation Error: Script compile error: Unsupported groovy language rule: 'type' text: 'Set' @ line 1, column 29.
I don't think `withSideEffect` is supported either.

Comment: That's too bad. I ran it on my laptop with TinkerGraph/Gremlin Console at the 3.3 level using my own graph and it did the job.

Comment: If by chance `withSideEffect` is supported you can just use a list instead of a Set

`
 g.withSideEffect('x', []).                        
     V().has('code',"AUS").store('x').                                    
     bothE().store('x').                                  
     otherV().store('x').                                 
     cap('x')
`

Comment: Unfortunately that was the first thing I've tried after the first one failed... But I gotta give you +1 for effort.

Answer (score 1):

This was the way it works with CosmosDB:

```
g.V().hasLabel("User")
    .as('Vertex') <------------------- alias for all users
    .map(bothE().fold())
    .as('Edges')
    .map(select('Vertex') <----------- this was the key. Map from the first step
        .bothE().otherV().fold())
    .as('RelatedVertices')
    .select('User', 'Edges', 'RelatedVertices')
```

Unfortunately, the `withSideEffect` doesn't seem to be supported by Microsoft.Azure.Graphs library, so the below way, proposed by [Kelvin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48244488/828023) which seems more elegant can't be used:

```
g.withSideEffect('x', [] as Set).                        
     V().hasLabel("user").store('x').                                    
     bothE().store('x').                                  
     otherV().store('x').                                 
     cap('x')
```