# Gremlin query returning graph traversal instead of edges

Tags: groovy, gremlin, graph-databases

I have a graph with some vertices that have edges towards each other (parent and child). Based off this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33676566/gremlin-get-all-incoming-and-outgoing-vertex-including-their-edges-and-directio)

This is what my code looks like

```
const showAllRelationships = async (target)=> {
var result = await g.V(target).bothE().otherV().path().by(__.valueMap(true));

console.log(result);
return result;
};
```

And this is the result I get.

```
GraphTraversal { graph: Graph {}, traversalStrategies: TraversalStrategies { strategies: [ [RemoteStrategy]
 ] }, bytecode: Bytecode { sourceInstructions: [], stepInstructions: [ [Array], [Array], [Array], [Array], [Array] ] }, traversers: null, sideEffects: null, _traversalStrategiesPromise: null, _traversersIteratorIndex: 0 }
```

What is wrong with this code that it isn't returning the edges?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add a Terminal Step to the end of your query in order for the query to be sent to the server:  https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.4.9/reference/#terminal-steps

Comment: sometimes its the silly little mistakes, all my other queries had .next on them. thank you!

Comment: No worries.  Someone is else bound to have the same issue and find this post in the future! :)